# linux RT scheduling

Tags: multithreading, process, scheduler, rt

Our product is running linux 2.6.32, and we have some user space processes which run periodically - 'keep alive - like' processes. We don't place hard requirements on these processes - they just need to run once in several seconds and refresh some watchdog.

We gave these processes a scheduling class of RR or FIFO with max priority, and yet, we see many false positives - it seems like they don't get the CPU for several seconds.
I find it very odd because I know that Linux, while not being a RT OS, can still yield very good performance (I see people talking about orders of several msec) - and I can't even make that the process run once in 5 sec.

The logic of Linux RT scheduler seems very straight forward and simple, so I suspected that these processes get blocked by something else - I/O contention, interrupts or kernel threads taking too long - but now I'm not so sure:
I wrote a really basic program to simulate such a process - it wakes up every 1 second and measures the time spent since the last time it finished running. The time measurement doesn't include blocking on any I/O as far as I understand, so the results printed by this process reflect the behavior of the scheduler:

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MICROSECONDSINASEC 1000000
#define MILLISECONDSINASEC 1000

int main()
{
    struct sched_param schedParam;
    struct timeval now, start;
    int spent_time = 0;
    time_t current_time;

    schedParam.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_RR);
    int retVal = sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, &schedParam);
    if (retVal != 0)
    {
        printf("failed setting RT sched");
        return 0;
    }

    gettimeofday(&start, 0);
    start.tv_sec -= 1;
    start.tv_usec += MICROSECONDSINASEC;

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        gettimeofday(&now, 0);
        now.tv_sec -= 1;
        now.tv_usec += MICROSECONDSINASEC;
        spent_time = MILLISECONDSINASEC * (now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + ((now.tv_usec -       start.tv_usec) / MILLISECONDSINASEC);

        FILE *fl = fopen("output_log.txt", "aw");

        if (spent_time > 1100)
        {
            time(&current_time);
            fprintf(fl,"\n (%s) - had a gap of %d [msec] instead of 1000\n",                       ctime(&current_time), spent_time);
        }

        fclose(fl);
        gettimeofday(&start, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I ran this process overnight on several machines - including ones that don't run our product (just plain Linux) and I still saw gaps of several seconds - even though I made sure the process DID get the priority - and I can't figure out why - technically this process should preeampt any other running process, so how can it wait so long to run?

A few notes:

1. I ran these processes mostly on virtual machines - so maybe there can be an intervention from the hypervisor. But in the past I've seen such behavior on physical machines as well.
2. Making the process RT did improve the results drastically, but not totally prevented the problem.
3. There are no other RT processes running on the machine except for the Linux migration and watchdog process (which I don't believe can cause starvation to my processes).

What can I do? I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

thanks!

Comment: Well, while the time measurement may not include blocking on any I/O, the file operations do.

Comment: You writing to an SSD that is nearly full?

Comment: Also, why open and close the log file even if you don't write anything?

Comment: hi, thanks for replying.  I'm doing file operation but they are not counted in the measurement. About opening and closing  - you are right of course, it's just that there was originally more code which did something in any case (which I removed). And no, I'm not using SSD.